# Open source 3D Geometry libraries?

Tags: c#, geometry

I'm working on a personal project that involves finding the intersections of tubes (thin walled cylinders).  It requires two main math computations I'm trying to find in a library or in sample code.
1)  The minimum distance between two lines.  (I've found code for this already)
2)  The two corresponding points on the two lines that are each closest to the other line.

I've found plenty of sites with the math on how to do #2, but no sample code of anyone implementing it.

I am fully capable of writing this from scratch based on the math, but I'd much prefer saving several hours of coding, testing, and verifying by finding existing code I can incorporate in my C# app.  Even if the sample is in another language, I can port things over to C# much faster than writing from scratch.

Since this is very much a "solved problem," I assume there has to be an open source library in some language already in existence, and re-inventing the wheel (and testing it and verifying it) would be a waste of time.  (And, as we all know, any time we can spare from life for "personal projects" is a scarce and valuable commodity.)

Answer (score 0):

There many open source library, if you familiar width javascript, you can try three.js, there is an implementation https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/CylinderGeometry.js

or you can find some ascriptscript library, like papervision3d
http://papervision3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as3/trunk/src/org/papervision3d/objects/primitives/Cylinder.as

Comment: I think you mis-read the question.  I don't need a library to generate the cylinder mesh/geometry.  I need a library to efficiently find the closest points on two skew lines, so that I can then compute the intersections of two or more cylinders.